# Getting compile error in Swift after inserting viewWillAppear function

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, ios8, viewwillappear

I have this piece of code down below that is intended to be a custom tabor controller. The problem is that when I build I get and error just if I have in the code the viewWillAppear function. If I comment it out the project builds and runs fine.

Here's the function:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if self.childViewControllers.count < 1 {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("viewController1", sender: self.buttons.0)
    }

}
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re mixing and matching Objective-C and Swift syntax a bit.

There are no square brackets involved in Swift method calls.  You just call them with `object.methodname()` (and no space needed or stylistically desired after the `object`).

This:

```
[self .performSegueWithIdentifier("viewController1", sender: self.buttons.0)]
```

will best-case be interpreted by Swift as taking the result from `performSegueWithIdentifier` and putting it in a single-element array (though that ought to compile, so there could be something else wrong).

Try just writing `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("viewController1", sender: self.buttons.0)` without the `[]` and space, and see if it either compiles or at least yields you a more useful error message.